# gRPC Java server leaks memory on large requests since updating JDK Docker image

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, memory-leaks, grpc

We have a gRPC server written in Java. The application is using SpringBoot version 2.5.7.

In an attempt to isolate the issue, I stripped the project down to contain only one unary gRPC endpoint that handles file uploads. The maximum size of an inbound message was increased to 400MB, and the files are being sent as a `ByteString` as part of the gRPC request:

```
// Upload an object with a unique ObjectIdentifier and corresponding object.
rpc UploadObject (UploadObjectRequest) returns (google.protobuf.Empty);

message UploadObjectRequest {
    ObjectIdentifier object_identifier = 1;
    bytes object = 2; // A byte array representing single object data.
}
```

Upon receiving the request, the server immediately returns a successful response to the client through the `responseObserver` object. The `ByteString` is discarded and is not written anywhere - We just send a response and return:

```
@Slf4j
@GRpcService
public class MyEndpoint extends MyServiceImplBase {
    @Override
    public void uploadObject(UploadObjectRequest request, StreamObserver<Empty> responseObserver) {
        responseObserver.onNext(Empty.getDefaultInstance());
        responseObserver.onCompleted();
    }
}
```

The application is deployed on Kubernetes (on 1 pod). We were using **openjdk:17.0.2-jdk** as a Docker image, until it got deprecated, then migrated to **amazoncorretto:17.0.7-al2023**.

Since migrating to the Amazon image, we are observing a memory leak, specifically in the direct buffer (non-heap) memory. To recreate and isolate the issue, I wrote a method that repeatedly invokes the endpoint with a large file (200MB):

```
@SneakyThrows
@Test
public void test() {
    while (true) {
    Channel channel = grpcClientChannelFactory.createGrpcChannel(host, port);
    MyServiceBlockingStub blockingStub = newBlockingStub(channel);

        final int numOfBytes = 200_000_000;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[numOfBytes];
        new Random().nextBytes(bytes);
        UploadObjectRequest uploadObjectRequest = UploadObjectRequest.newBuilder()
                .setObjectIdentifier(
                        ObjectIdentifier.newBuilder()
                                .setNamespace("namespace")
                                .setKey("testFile")
                )
                .setObject(ByteString.copyFrom(bytes))
                .build();

        blockingStub
                .withCallCredentials(new JwtCallCredential(JWT))
                .uploadObject(uploadObjectRequest);
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

Below is a comparison of memory-related metrics between the two images. Other than the Docker image, the source is identical in both cases.

I should mention that we tried numerous other images that are recommended as alternatives to openjdk:17.0.2-jdk, like amazoncorretto:21.0.0-al2023, eclipse-temurin:latest, ibmjava:latest, ibm-semeru-runtimes:open-17.0.8.1_1-jdk. The memory leak was reproduces in the same fashion in all of then. OpenJDK is the only image where we do not observe this issue.

**Using openjdk:17.0.2-jdk:**

container_memory_usage_bytes
[image]

jvm_buffer_memory_used_bytes (direct memory bytes)
[image]

jvm_buffer_count_buffers (direct memory num of buffers)
[image]

jvm_memory_used_bytes (heap memory bytes)
[image]

**Using openjdk:amazoncorretto:17.0.7-al2023:**

container_memory_usage_bytes
[image]

jvm_buffer_memory_used_bytes (direct memory bytes)
[image]

jvm_buffer_count_buffers (direct memory num of buffers)
[image]

jvm_memory_used_bytes (heap memory bytes)
[image]

Any insight into what might be causing this is appreciated, as well as suggestions for how I might further isolate the issue and find out what is the root cause.

Comment: This is a great question, but please follow StackOverflow practice and paste your code directly, not as images.  (The graphs can stay.)

Comment: Edited, thanks!

Comment: What version of gRPC-Java are you using?

Also, if you can narrow it down to a specific place in gRPC-Java where you think the memory is getting leaked, you could post of their Github repo for better response times.

Comment: We are currently using version 4.7.0. As far as narrowing it down, I can see that memory start growing without bound once I start sending large requests to the server using a ByteString field in my requests. How would you advise to narrow it down further?

Comment: To clarify, the version 4.7.0 is of io.github.lognet:grpc-spring-boot-starter.

Comment: What version of gRPC Java would that be? Also I posted a response to the same query in grpc-java github repo https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/10589

Comment: @SanP Thanks for the response, and sorry again for the delay! I have responded to the github issue.